# O365 Group Based Licensing not Working

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-connect

I have synced our local Active Directory with Azure AD using Azure Connect. I'm trying to assign Office 365 Licensing to Security Groups on Azure Active Directory, but when I clic on "License" inside the group properties, the "Products" tab appear disabled, but for the users the licensing assigment works fine, this only happend with groups.

There some parameter that the Security Groups has to have enabled to be assigned with product licensing? Or do I have to enable something else on Azure Active Directory?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps -

1. Sign in to the Azure portal with an Administrator account. To manage licenses, the account must be a global administrator role or user account administrator.
2. Select All services in the left navigation pane, and then select Azure Active Directory. You can add this pane to Favorites or pin it to the portal dashboard.
3. On the Azure Active Directory pane, select Licenses to open a pane where you can see and manage all licensable products in the tenant.
4. Under All products, select both Office 365 Enterprise E3 and Enterprise Mobility + Security by selecting the product names. To start the assignment, select Assign at the top of the pane.

[image]

5. On the Assign license pane, click Users and groups to open the Users and groups pane. Search for the group name HR Department, select the group, and then be sure to confirm by clicking Select at the bottom of the pane.

[image]

6. On the Assign license pane, click Assignment options (optional), which displays all service plans included in the two products that we selected previously. Find Yammer Enterprise and turn it Off to disable that service from the product license. Confirm by clicking OK at the bottom of Assignment options.

[image]

7. To complete the assignment, on the Assign license pane, click Assign at the bottom of the pane.
8. A notification is displayed in the upper-right corner that shows the status and outcome of the process. If the assignment to the group couldn't be completed (for example, because of pre-existing licenses in the group), click the notification to view details of the failure.

Note: You can start the same assignment from an alternative location: Users and groups in Azure AD. Go to Azure Active Directory > Users and groups > All groups. Then find the group, select it, and go to the Licenses tab. The Assign button on top of the pane opens the license assignment pane.

Reference: [Assign licenses to users by group membership in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-groups-assign)